# ASP.net MVC: JQuery DataTable Styling problem with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

i use JQuery DataTable plugin in a Asp.net MVC Project. JQuery, DataTable and Bootstrap are installed by Nugets. Adding the reference jquery.dataTables.min.css to the Layout make a styling troubles and problems.
the order of call:

```
<head>
    <link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/website.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/website.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Thank you !

Comment: Try moving jquery.dataTables.min.css to after bootstrap.min.css (and probably after jquery-ui.css)

Comment: Same problem :  styling doesnt work !

Comment: Your question needs more detail. What "troubles and problems"? Please see [ask] and take the [tour].